# How to split an image in multiple parts in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

I try to build a simple puzzle game with SwiftUI.
There is a square image, let's say 300 * 300. I want to either split it into nine 100 * 100 images or show 100 * 100 parts of the original image.

`clipped()` modifier afaik only allows to cut parts of the image but not to select for example the middle part of the original image.
Anyone with a hint how to start there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.offset` to move the image into position before applying a frame and a clip shape. Something like:

```swift
VStack {
    ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { row in
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { col in
                theImage
                    .offset(x: CGFloat(-100 * col), y: CGFloat(-100 * row))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .topLeading)
                    .clipShape(Rectangle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example, using this image:

```swift
private var theImage: some View {
    Image(systemName: "tortoise")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .padding(20)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(.yellow)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]